# Nagios Connection

Tags: nagios

Besides SSH, is there another protocol connection to Nagios?

Answer (score 4):

All the answers are good but let me give some new precisions:

- **NRPE** is the official daemon for polling monitoring. Moreover you can use it over SSL to secure your communications. Another advantage is you can use plugins you wrote to monitor your node: so you can imagine to monitore everything you want if you can script it.
- **SNMP** : really useful to monitor network devices (like switchs, routers...) because this protocol is implemented everywhere. But only SNMP v3 is really secured and you can monitor only metrics declared in the MIBs of your node/network device. So you could be limited for monitoring (and add new entries in the MIB is not really easy).
- **SSH** : really secured and you can do the same job as NRPE but it could be painful to maintain the config (with the public key deploiement...)

Answer (score 3):

[NSCA](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/download/contrib/documentation/misc/NSCA_Setup.pdf) also.  We use [NRPE](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf) to drive checks that are performed often (every X mins), and NSCA for the infrequent ones (hourly, daily, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is the NRPE proprietary protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SNMP** protocol as well to have passive states from your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Besides SSH, is there another protocol connection to Nagios?
also you can using http to connect to Nagios, Nagios has cgi for you to do that.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.